# Does lowering temperature of a gas make it easier to compress?

Tags: pressure, kinetic-theory-of-gases, ideal-gas

My teacher said that for ideal gases,

> the lower the temperature, the lower the kinetic energy of a gas will be, and it will be easier to compress the gas.

Using the ideal gas equation $PV=nRT$, if the volume is constant, a decrease in temperature will cause a decrease in the pressure of the gas. That will make it easier to compress. Will the volume remain constant, or will it change?

Comment: Why gas molecules will come closer on lowering the temperature??

Comment: The kinetic energy decreases and they cannot move freely anymore. It is similar to the way water molecules come closer and form ice when temperature is lowered

Comment: Since you are saying that water molecules come closer to form ice then why don't volume of water decreases (i don't see any decrease)

Comment: Sorry I actually gave a wrong example since "Water is the only known non-metallic substance that expands when it freezes; its density decreases and it expands approximately 9% by volume". Source:http://www.lpi.usra.edu/education/explore/ice/activities/ice_action/expanding_ice/

Comment: So,give me a suitable answer of "Why gas molecules will come closer on lowering the temperature" so that i can write my answer

Comment: I don't know. I though the lowering of kinetic energy caused them to come closer. I guess I am wrong.

Comment: YEs this is the case,i think you should edit your question or add a suitable explaination of your argument,otherwise people are eager of downvote questions here

Comment: Come to chat if you are still confused.

Comment: You first had to define what you mean with "easier to compress" the gas. I guess that for any reasonable definition you will find that easiness of compression will rather depend on pressure than on temperature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compressing a gas by applying an external force means to work against the force the gas exerts on the walls of its container, i.e. its pressure.

The definition of [compressibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility)

$$\beta = -\frac{1}{V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial p} \tag{1}$$

for an [ideal gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas) with the well-known equation of state

$$p V = n R T \tag{2}$$

gives

$$\beta = -\frac{1}{V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial p} = \frac{1}{V} \frac{n R T}{p^2} = \frac{1}{p} \tag{3}$$

which is independent of the temperature $T$.

For non-ideal gases there will be higher order terms that also depend on temperature.

It is also worth noting that at the [critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics)) the compressibility of a real gas is infinite. So if you are below the critical temperature you will be able to compress the gas more easily at a state (the critical point) with higher temperature.